# How do I display imported images at actual size?

Tags: import, image, grid-layouts, size

I know that this is an extremely basic question, but I am having a lot of trouble finding the answer in the documentation.

When I import an image (for example, `Import[test.png]`), Mathematica often displays it smaller than the *actual* size of the image. How do I force Mathematica to display the imported image at actual size?

I may want to display such images using `Grid`.  For example, suppose that `fname` is a list of ***.png** file names. Then I may want to import and display all of those images using a command like:

```
fname = FileNames["*.png"];
table = Transpose[{fname, Table[Import[fname[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[fname]}]}];
Grid[table]
```

and I'd like the images displayed at actual size.

I know that this is a very basic question, but I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Programmatically I would use:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

Image[img, Magnification -> 1]
```

Manually you can right-click on the image and select `Actual Size`.

---

*Edit:* Although not as robust as what follows a simple solution to the resizing that takes place in `Row`, `Grid`, etc. is to wrap the `Image` or `Graphics` in [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html).

---

Within an `Image` there is raster data of a particular dimension:

```
Dimensions @ ImageData @ img
```

> {512, 512, 3}

This is a 512 x 512 pixel image with three channels.  Additionally the `Image` has options:

```
Options[img]
```

> {ColorSpace -> "RGB", ImageSize -> Automatic, Interleaving -> True, Magnification -> Automatic}

The two options that control the displayed image size are `ImageSize` and `Magnification`.

When you use the the context menu to set **Actual Size** you remove (reset) the `Magnification` option and set `ImageSize -> All`.  If you select a **Magnification** level you set `ImageSize -> All` *and* a `Magnification` value.

When you change the size of an image interactively by dragging the corners of the bounding box you remove (reset) the `Magnification` option an set a specific `ImageSize` value, e.g. `ImageSize -> {171., Automatic}`.

When you select **Automatic Size** you remove (reset) both options.

If numeric values for both options are given within `Image` the magnification is ignored:

```
Image[img, Magnification -> 40, ImageSize -> 200]
```

The `Magnification` option can also be used outside of `Image`, and it does not work the same as when it is set inside `Image`.

When used inside it prevents automatic scaling of the image, and it combines with Notebook magnification meaning that using `Image[img, Magnification -> 2]` inside a Notebook with magnification 50% produces a 1:1 image.

When used in `Style` as in `Style[img, Magnification -> 2]` it does not prevent automatic scaling of the image to fit the window *if* the two options within `Image` are either `Automatic` or not present.  Further, this magnification level *overrides* the Notebook magnification rather than combining with it, but *combines* with the `Image` setting.

One may display the image raster 1:1 regardless of Notebook zoom for an arbitrary image using:

```
Style[Image[img, ImageSize -> All, Magnification -> 1], Magnification -> 1]
```

Comment: Note that this works as it should only IF Notebook's `Magnification` is set to 100% AND global `Magnification` in the `$FrontEnd` options is also set to 100%. I don't know if there a way to display an image in its actual size independently of these options.

Comment: @Alexey you could always use: `CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Image[img, Magnification -> 1], Magnification -> 1]]`

Comment: ... or just `ExpressionCell[Image[img, Magnification -> 1], Magnification -> 1]` if we wish just to show it in the standard `"Output"` cell. Brilliant!

Comment: @Alexey I forgot about `Style` -- see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for detailed analysis. Does `Style` have any advantages as compared to `ExpressionCell`?

Comment: @Alexey it's a few less characters which I always like.  Other than that it produces a different output structure, which may or may not be useful in some way.  `Cell[BoxData[
  StyleBox[GraphicsBox[TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData[]]]]]]]` vs `Cell[BoxData[
  InterpretationBox[Cell[BoxData[GraphicsBox[TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData[]]]]]]]]]`

Answer (score 8):

I guess:

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]; 
Image[#, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[#]] &@i
```

will do.

Comment: Or, even simpler: `Image[i,ImageSize -> All]`