# TextCell going awry due to ImageResolution (in Mathematica 7)

Tags: graphics, formatting, version-7

Can anyone see how to fix this text display?  The example is from a larger project.  I need to export the graphic at high resolution, but the text is going wrong.

```
text = StringTake[
   ExampleData[{"Text", "DonQuixoteIEnglish"}], {110600, 110914}];

a = Graphics[{{LightBlue, Rectangle[{0, -0.21}, {1, -0.04}]},
   Inset[Graphics[{{LightYellow, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {450, 40}]},
      Inset[
       TextCell[text, LineSpacing -> {0, 16}, TextJustification -> 1],
       Center, Center, {450, 40}]},
     BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, PlotRange -> {{0, 450}, {0, 40}}],
    {0.5, -0.155}, Center, {0.9, Automatic}]},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-0.21, -0.04}}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

```
Rasterize[a, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

[image]

N.B.  This problem is happening on Mathematica 7.  I just checked on Mathematica 9 and it works ok, but I need to run it on version 7.

Comment: in V9 `Rasterize[a,ImageResolution->300]` works fine (it gives the same image as your first one).

Comment: @kguler - yes, thanks, I just tried.  I need it for version 7 though.

Comment: V8 works fine two. How about adding Rasterize[a, ImageResolution -> 300, **ImageSize -> 600**]

Comment: @s.s.o. That works for the example, but when used in `Export["a.png", a, ImageResolution -> 300, ImageSize -> 600]` my output is not high resolution.  It's the same as `Export["a.png", a]`.  Thanks though.

Comment: How about increasing the image resolution and setting image size in export rather than using default values.

Comment: @s.s.o - That's what I tried in my previous comment.  `ImageSize` overrode `ImageResolution`.  If I use a larger `ImageSize` such as in `Export["a.png", a, ImageResolution -> 300, ImageSize -> 2600]` the text appears too small.  Mr.Wizard has come up with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
Rasterize[Magnify[a, 1], ImageResolution -> 300]
```

Comment: Could you explain why this helps/may help? Can't check for myself, as I don't have 7 installed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Very nice.  Thanks.  It works for the final export too, with `Export["a.png", Magnify[a, 1], ImageResolution -> 300]`

Comment: @Sjoerd I don't have an explanation, at least not right now.  I only know that `Magnify` has helped in similar situations.  Perhaps later I'll try to dig out *why* this helps, if the operations are not out of reach.  Certainly magnification is [entwined](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8592/121) with ImageSize, etc.