# Spacer and Text in Graphics going Awry (in Mathematica 7)

Tags: graphics, text, version-7, alignment

Use of a vertical `Spacer` in justified text inside a graphic isn't working as required.  The result in the green box looks right, but when this is placed in a graphic the spacing is messed up.  Is there some way to fix it?

```
g1 = StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "BeowulfModern"}], {4740, 5200}];
g2 = StringTake[g1, 319] <> "\n";
g3 = StringDrop[g1, 319];
g4 = Row[{g2, Spacer[{0, 30}], g3}];

TextCell[g4, LineSpacing -> {0, 16}, TextJustification -> 1, 
 Background -> LightGreen]

Graphics[{
  LightBlue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {500, 140}], Black,
  Inset[TextCell[g4, LineSpacing -> {0, 16}, TextJustification -> 1],
   {0, 0}, {Left, Bottom}, {500, Automatic}]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 140}}, ImageSize -> 500,
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Courier New", FontSize -> 12}]
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine in version 9. I don't have a 7 so can not test it. A wild guess is something goes wrong with the baseline alignment.. Maybe try `Column` instead of `Row` in `g4`?

Comment: Chris, I found this question deleted but I can duplicate both the problem and the solution so I undeleted it.  If this is a problem I can delete it again but I am assuming you thought it was of no interest, yet it is.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I thought I was going to need the `Magnify` trick again, but an option sufficed.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15766/363

Answer (score 2):

Problem fixed with the `TextCell` option `CellBaseline`, i.e.:-

```
Graphics[{LightBlue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {500, 140}], Black,
  Inset[TextCell[g4, LineSpacing -> {0, 16}, TextJustification -> 1,
    CellBaseline -> Bottom],
   {0, 0}, {Left, Bottom}, {500, Automatic}]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 140}}, ImageSize -> 500,
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Courier New", FontSize -> 12}]
```

By the way, this method is handy to give a line separation *less* than "\n" would provide.