# Why is Text in an Image cut off?

Tags: graphics, image

I want to create a long, skinny `Image` containing only text.

This makes a square image of the default size.

```
Image@Graphics[
 {
  FontSize->20,
  Text["now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country"]
 }
]
```

[image]

So I prescribe the dimensions I want:

```
Image@Graphics[
 {
  FontSize->20,
  Text["now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country"]
 },
 ImageSize->{1000,30}
]
```

[image]

and the result is cropped well inside the `ImageSize` so some of the text is missing. But the `Graphics` alone is appearing correctly.

```
Graphics[
 {
  FontSize->20,
  Text["now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country"]
 },
 ImageSize->{1000,30}
]
```

[image]

Why does `Image` mysteriously crop the input?

Comment: Why not `Style[Text[
  "now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country"], FontSize -> 20]//Rasterize` ?

Comment: I believe this issue has been covered before but I cannot find the question.  Please help me look for it.  @RodLm : Probably because he has other `Graphics` primitives in practice.

Comment: You need to apply the `ImageSize` to `Image`, not `Graphics`. Try `Image[Graphics[Text[Style["now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their 
country", 20]]], ImageSize -> {600, 30}]`

Comment: @m_goldberg I believe this question has been asked before; can you help me find it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I wouldn't be surprised if it were so, but a half=hour of searching didn't turn up anything. Sorry.

Comment: @m_goldberg Sincere thanks for your efforts, and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Related?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15763/textcell-going-awry-due-to-imageresolution-in-mathematica-7

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's quite possibly what I was thinking of, since I replied to it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Image` defaults to a certain size, but can be adjusted with its own `ImageSize`.

```
g=Graphics[{FontSize -> 20, Text["now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country"]};
Image[g, ImageSize -> {1000, 30}]
```

Comment: it seems you need to manually work out the aspect ratio..?

Answer (score 1):

a bit of tweaking..

```
rastertext[ht_] := Function[{s}, Module[{},
          (*ht=approx pixel ht of M*)
   ImageCrop@
     Image[Graphics[{{FontSize -> 1.5 ht, Text[s]}}], 
                ImageSize -> 5  ht  { StringLength[s] , 1}]]]
```

the trick here is to scale the fontsize with the desided height, give ample room in the imagesize, then crop the result

```
z1 = rastertext[18]@(StringJoin @@ Table["M", {20}] ) 
z2 = rastertext[18]@(StringJoin @@ Table["M", {5}] ) 
z3 = rastertext[18]@(StringJoin @@ Table["M", {1}] )
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

verify we got the height right

```
ImageDimensions /@ {z1, z2, z3}

(* {{480, 18}, {120, 18}, {24, 18}} *)

rastertext[18]@"now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country"
```

[image]

for fun..

```
words = rastertext[18] /@  
       StringSplit[
         "now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country"];
p = {0, 0};
Graphics[Last@Last@Reap[
           Do[d = ImageDimensions[w]; Sow[Inset[w, p, {0, 0}, d]]; 
           p += {d[[1]] + 15, 0}; 
           If[p[[1]] > 300, p = {0, p[[2]] - 30}], {w, words}]], 
           PlotRange -> {{0, 350}, {-60, 25}}]
```

[image]

..need more tweaking to get the baselines aligned..

```
rastertext[ht_] := Function[{s}, Module[{},
  (*ht=approx pixel ht of M*)
  pad = If[ Length[StringPosition[s, {"g", "q", "p", "y", "j"}]] == 0 , ht/3, 0];
  ImagePad[ ImageCrop@
    Image[Graphics[{{FontSize -> 1.5 ht, Text[s]}}], 
        ImageSize -> 5  ht  { StringLength[s] , 1}], {{0, 0}, {pad, 0}},White]]]
```

[image]