# Best solution to insert text at defined position into image

Tags: graphics, image, rasterize

**What is the best solution to insert text at defined poition into image?**

I saw this [question/answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28427/why-is-text-in-an-image-cut-off) but it does not help me for my examples below.

I tried the following and find some strange behaviour:

```
image = Image[Array[0 &, {200, 400}]];
```

Example 1:

```
text = "This is a very long text";
textImage = 
  textImage = Rasterize[Style[text, FontFamily -> "Calibri", 30]];
composedImage = Show[image, textImage]
```

[image]

Example 2:

```
text = "This is a very long text This is a very long text This is a very long text This is a very long text";
textImage = 
  textImage = Rasterize[Style[text, FontFamily -> "Calibri", 30]];
composedImage = Show[image, textImage]
```

Here the text is cropped.

[image]

Example 3:

```
text = "This is a very long text This is a very long text This is a very long text This is a very long text This is a very long text";
textImage = 
  textImage = Rasterize[Style[text, FontFamily -> "Calibri", 30]];
composedImage = Show[image, textImage]
```

I don't understand why here the text is wrapped but not left aligned.
It seems that when the text exceeds a certain length (probably depending on text size) this happens.

[image]

---

**What would you propose to insert text into an Image?**

Comment: use the option `LineIndent -> 0` in `Style`. Default value is `1.`.

Comment: @kglr: If I put `LineIndent -> 0` in example 3 I get 2 rows now left aligned and wrapped. How can I have a single line although it is too long and not everything seen? In general: I believe that my way how I insert text is not the correct one. There must be a more elegant solution, where I also can set the position.

Comment: mrz, to get a single line use the option `LineBreakWithin -> False` in `Style`.

Comment: @kglr: Merry Christmas and thank you for your help.

Comment: mrz, Merry Christmas to you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To supress line  breaks you can use the option [`LineBreakWithin -> False`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineBreakWithin.html) in `Style`:

```
text = "This is a very long text This is a very long text This is a very long text This is a
  very long text This is a very long text";
textImage = Rasterize[Style[text, FontFamily -> "Calibri", 30, LineBreakWithin -> False]];
composedImage = Show[image, textImage]
```

[image]

To prevent indents use the option [`LineIndent -> 0`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineIndent.html):

```
textImage = Rasterize[Style[text, FontFamily -> "Calibri", 30, LineIndent -> 0]]
composedImage = Show[image, textImage]
```

[image]