# How to set magnification of image to 75%

Tags: formatting, image

Right click on an output image, choose magnification. There are 25%, 50%, 100% etc. But how can I set to 75%?

Comment: Related: [How do I display imported images at actual size?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8583/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know how to do it using the menu, since this setting is not there. But you always use the `Magnify` command?

```
 r=Image[ {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
r15 = Magnify[r, 1.5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
r75 = Magnify[r, .75]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
r75  (*showing that new image will keep new magnification*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, but when I copy magnified image to another ranotebook, it restores its original size. So strange.

Comment: Really? I tried, but failed. You will find that dimension of image doesn't change.

Comment: OIC. Maybe my paste mode is wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I voted for both prior answers, each of which demonstrates a method to change the magnification of a graphical object.  However, only the `Image` Option `Magnification` persists when the image is copied.  This is because using `Magnify` sets the `Magnification` option in a `StyleBox` when it is rendered:

```
rose = Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"];

Magnify[rose, 0.75] // ToBoxes // Rest
```

> ```
> StyleBox[Magnification -> 0.75 Inherited, StripOnInput -> False]
> ```

If you copy-and-paste the entire output Cell this StyleBox is preserved, but not if you copy only the image.  Similarly using `Style`, except that when using `Magnify` the coefficient `Inherited` is used which makes total magnification cumulative rather than absolute:

```
Style[rose, Magnification -> 0.75] // ToBoxes // Rest
```

> ```
> StyleBox[Magnification -> 0.75, StripOnInput -> False]
> ```

When the option set in `Image` is rendered it appears in the `GraphicsBox` which is preserved even when the image alone is copied:

```
Image[rose, Magnification -> 0.75] // ToBoxes // Rest
```

> ```
> GraphicsBox[BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics", ImageSize -> Magnification[0.75], 
>  ImageSizeRaw -> {223, 164}, PlotRange -> {{0, 223}, {0, 164}}]
> ```

An equivalent method (for Images) is to use `Show` rather than `Image`:

```
Show[rose, Magnification -> 0.75] // ToBoxes // Rest
```

> ```
> GraphicsBox[BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics", ImageSize -> Magnification[0.75], 
>  ImageSizeRaw -> {223, 164}, PlotRange -> {{0, 223}, {0, 164}}]
> ```

This has the advantage however of not rasterizing `Graphics` objects, so it is more general and less destructive:

```
gr = Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}];

Image[gr, Magnification -> 0.75] // Head
Show[gr, Magnification -> 0.75]  // Head
```

> ```
> Image
>
> Graphics
> ```

Please also see my answer to [How do I display imported images at actual size?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8583/how-do-i-display-imported-images-at-actual-size/8592#8592) for examples of the way the options `ImageSize` and `Magnification` interact.

Answer (score 3):

You might do as follows. Let us take the example image from Help:

```
rose = Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"]
```

It is an image:

```
rose // Head

(* Image *)
```

Now the construct

```
Image[rose, Magnification -> 0.75]
```

gives you the expected. Compare:

```
{Image[rose, Magnification -> 1], Image[rose, Magnification -> 0.75]}
```

Should look as follows:

[image]
Here the first two roses represent the output of the line above, while the third rose is the result of the copy-paste of the 75%-sized one in another notebook. So its size stays 75% of the original as we see.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between resizing an image and resizing the display of the image. Consider:

```
r = Image[{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}];
r100 = ImageResize[r, 100];
rNot100 = Image[r, ImageSize -> 100];
rmag = Image[r, Magnification -> 33.3]
```

All three of the resized images `r100`, `rNot100` and `rmag` look the same:

[image]

But if we check on the actual dimensions:

```
ImageDimensions /@ {r, r100, rNot100, rmag}
{{3, 3}, {100, 100}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}
```

we can see that `ImageResize` changes the number of pixels in the underlying data while `ImageSize` and `Magnification` only change the displayed image. Which one you want will depend on what your goal is.