# What governs images resizing in the FrontEnd environment

Tags: front-end, image, implementation-details, scaling

What is responsible for the middle [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html) images' size? And why single image row is different?

```
{#, Row[{#, #}], Row[{#}]} & @ RandomImage[1, {100, 100}]
```

[image]

I know I can prevent that with mapping with [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html) but I would like to have more understanding about what happens.

I thought it is related to some styles but I haven't found anything related in `Core.nb` under [`ImageGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageGraphics.html) or [`RowDefault`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RowDefault.html) styles.

There are related options like `ImageSizeAction` or `ImageSizeMultipliers` but I've failed to find connection with the case.

---

It doesn't seem predictable, since here overall size is larger yet nothing is resized:

```
{#, Row[{#, #, #, #, #}], Row[{#}]} &@RandomImage[1, {50, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: Related questions for background: [(8583)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8583/121), [(39996)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39996/121),
[(72573)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72573/121)

Comment: I have looked everywhere I can think of and I found nothing.  This may be deeply embedded in the system.

Answer (score 10):

There are two distinctions to be made here.  Both `Row` and `List` will resize graphics objects if they are above a certain threshold size, and that threshold size is different.

### List

`List` will resize a graphics object when its width is larger than 180 pixels, and then further reduce its size if the width is over 360

```
Manipulate[Labeled[
  {RandomImage[1, {n, 200}]},
  "Width = " <> IntegerString[n]], {{n, 50}, 50, 1000, 1}, 
  ContentSize -> {300, 400}]
```

[image]

A similar effect is seen with the height with a threshold value of 430 pixels,

```
Manipulate[Labeled[
  {RandomImage[1, {200, n}]},
  "Height = " <> IntegerString[n]], {{n, 50}, 50, 1000, 1}, 
 ContentSize -> {300, 400}]
```

[image]

### Row

Unlike `List`, `Row` will not resize a graphic if it is the only element in the list,

```
Row[{RandomImage[1, {300, 200}]}]
Row[{RandomImage[1, {500, 200}]}]
```

[image]

But it will resize if there is more than one element in the list,

```
Manipulate[
  Labeled[
   Row[{#, , #, , #, , #}] &@RandomImage[1, {n, 200}],
   "Width = " <> IntegerString[n]]
  , {{n, 50}, 50, 1000, 1}, ContentSize -> {500, 250}]
```

[image]

Things get even more complicated when you combine the two functions, such that you have `Row` objects inside the `List` along with other graphics

```
Manipulate[
 Labeled[
  {#, Row[{#, , #, , #, , #}]} &@RandomImage[1, {n, 200}],
  "Width = " <> IntegerString[n]]
 , {{n, 50}, 50, 1000, 1}, ContentSize -> {500, 250}]
```

[image]

So there appears to be some kind of rhyme and reason to it, but it'd take a bit more work like this to exactly nail down when it is doing this and why.

Comment: `List[graphics]` will resize the graphics if it is larger than a threshold value, but `Row[List[graphics]]` will not.  However, `Row[List[graphics,graphics]]` will resize the graphics.  I don't pretend to understand why these rules are in place, I just poke it in different ways to see how it responds, and it is predictable.

Comment: FrontEnd uses the [`ImageSizeMultipliers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSizeMultipliers.html) option settings to determine the size of the resized image. Wrap the images with `Style[..., ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}]` to disable resizing.

Comment: Disabling the  resizing is easy enough to do - another way is to give an `ImageSize` option to each `Graphics`. But I feel like the question here is to figure out the resizing, why and when it happens.