# How to override the style definitions in Reference.nb?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, customization

Mathematica 11.1.0 introduces a new look to its documentation, which doesn't look good on my Windows machine. After some digging it turns out the styles are largely defined in `Mathematica\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets\Wolfram\Reference.nb`. But modifying this file directly triggers a beep. What's the recommended way to override these styles?

Comment: Here is an example of modifying a built-in stylesheet: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123484/280. And here is another  example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81016/280.

Comment: Thank you! These examples help a lot.