# Screen resolution issue in 13.0

Tags: front-end

It was to be expected that new 13.0 version does not resolve the old and well-known magic issue with resolution and DPI.

I have 15'' laptop with full-HD screen (1920*1080). In version 12.3 it was an issue with blur in all the notebook elements (text, buttons, etc.)

Recently I have updated to 13.0 version. Just look:

[image]

It is 100% scale of the notebook. If one do not see the problem, try to look one more time:

[image]

Now there is no blur (thanks!), but elements of the notebook ARE HUGE. Any manipulations with program properties (Windows built-in high resolution rescaling options) and manipulations with Option Inspector do not help.

I have tried to do:

1. reduce Magnification parameter
2. switch on/off SreenCompatibilityMode
3. manipulate with BitDepth and Resolution parameters

Nothing of the mentioned work. Current settings are:

[image]

I do not know what should I try in order to resolve this issue. I have checked Wolfram forums, well-known screen resolution questions on this Stack. The answer is still unknown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you reported this issue to wolfram support?

Comment: @CATrevillian according to Stack & Wolfram Community the problem is well-known for years (see https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/785249)

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/260927/72682 see the answer there about a possible workaround. Make sure to restart Mathematica after applying the fix.

Comment: @flinty thanks! but it also does not work)

Comment: The workaround mentioned in that post only applies if your display setting in the Settings app is set to 100% (aka 96 dpi).  Supposedly it is set to 125% (120 dpi), therefore that setting is ignored.

Comment: My display is 80 DPI (2160p but 55") so the 1.333 which is 96 DPI is better for me that without 1.333 since that is only 72 DPI. You read that info from EDID! Alas, in my case HDMI EDID says it is 77", while it is 55". Wow. How can you set 80 DPI?

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников, I don't believe a.) Windows allows you enter a custom DPI anymore and b.) when it did, would allow you to specify something lower than 96.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников it is default settings, I do not changed anything

Comment: @ihojnicki I'll try it today, thanks for response

Comment: I had to set "Global Magnification" to 75% in "Settings"

Comment: 15" with 1920x1080 is actually 146.86 DPI (https://www.sven.de/dpi/). So it should be even bigger, no? AFAIK, it works as expected. You are supposed to render stuff bigger to accomodate higher DPI (imagine your smartphone with 500 DPI) and render stuff with less ClearType or gray type (subpixel rendering, first is in colors). Bluriness happens due to actual mismatch but that is fixed! Cleartype off can fix it further, try it! Can you compare to Macbook??