# Characters and prompt are offset when typing in a text cell using MM13.1

Tags: bugs, front-end, text, input, editing

I noticed on my system (Windows 10 and MM13.1) that when I create a text cell (ALT 7)
the longer my sentence is the more offset the cursor appears from where I am. When using the left arrow to go back the cursor just overlaps with a character!
So the first picture shows the position of the cursor. There is NO space between the last s and the cursor!
[image]

The same sentence but shorter..

[image]

I restarted my laptop, MM13.1 etc.
[edit]
I noticed that when I use non existing words this does not happen. It looks like the frontend is actively "repositioning" recognized English words.
I disabled the toolbar to no avail.

Comment: I reproduce the problem with version 13.1.0 on Windows 10 x64. I tried to switch on the [`"ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261006/280), but it seemingly doesn't help with this. The problem is not present in version 12.3.1.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov When I use PrintOut Screen environment it's working. But this is not a workaround :). I think they use an AI somewhere.. "Good" to know you have the same issue

Comment: Yes it was a rather unfortunate bug in 13.1.

Comment: @ihojnicki Is it already fixed in the development version?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Not yet, but it is actively being worked on.

Comment: @ihojnicki If I can help testing just let me know. When I type a sentence with random characters all the words are underlined (red due too spelling control) but the effect described is not present. A sentence like "Wssd fsdfsd sdf sf sdfsf sdsdf dfsfsd fsfs sdsdfsdsdf sdfsdf dfsd sdfs fggh jyjyu nuy y  ae ew sdf  rwers ddf s df sdfsdfdsfs  sdfsd d fsdfsdfs sdffsdsf fsdf sdf sdfsd werwrwer "

Comment: @ihojnicki When I switch to German (preferences Language setting) the effect also disappears. It seems it's only related to the English language?

Comment: @Lou, it is going to be font, text run specific.

Comment: @ihojnicki is there a workaround of a specific font to choose that you’re aware of?

Comment: @Lou, not specifically, no.  There should be an update in the near future that will resolve this though.