# Why in Mathematica 13 do imported PDFs have lower image quality?

Tags: front-end, import, image, rendering, version-13

I'm finding images imported into Mathematica 13 notebooks are noticeably pixelated. (Oddly, pasting an image into a notebook cell does not have this problem.) Has the default changed for some import option?

Example figure generation with color and text:

```
g1 = Graphics[{
    {LightGray, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}]},
    {Black, Circle[{1, 1}, 1]},
    {Thick, Blue, Circle[{1, 1}, Sqrt[2]]},
    {Blue, Text[Style["text", 20], {1, 1}]}
    }, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 144];
Export["/temp/temp.pdf", g1] ;(* WARNING: this will overwrite temp.pdf *)
First@Import["/temp/temp.pdf"]
```

Mathematica 12.3:

[image: Mma12 outcome]

Mathematica 13:

[image: Mma 13 outcome]

Comment: I found the following. The PDF file export is not the problem. I Created pdf file from V13 and V12. Importing the V13 PDF file into V12 shows good display, same as with V12 own exported PDF. The PDF files seems to be the same. This tells me the problem is with either the import in V13 or some font settings in V13 which affects this. Do not know. More investigation is needed.  Try it yourself and you will see. Import the PDF created from V13 into V12.   May be report this to WRI.

Comment: @Nasser Yes that's right: the imports are the problem. The export in the example is just to allow easy testing.

Comment: They changed some settings for screen resolution in V13. I wonder if this has anything to do with it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 As you can see from the accepted answer, the actual problem discussed here is quite different from the question you linked, and isn't necessarily related to PDF import. I is a common problem of rendering of images in version 13.0.0.

Comment: Strongly related WC thread: "[Working with Graphics on Windows in a pixel perfect way](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2475442)."

Comment: @MichaelE2 The OP had't specified which subversion of the version 12 they used. Starting from version 12.2, the default import element for PDF is Image. I reproduce the OP's output with version 12.3.1.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The only clarification there could be that all these apply only to the Windows OS, but I can't be sure in this statement because I hadn't tried other OS. My answer is perfectly valid irrespectively of the subversion of version 12 used by the OP. What is important in my mind is that the question is very short and directly compares importing and pasting an image, which implies working with raster images (on Windows).

Comment: @MichaelE2 The only person so far who sees a Problem (!) is you. There are so many duplicate and even trashy questions on this site, and nobody cares. This question (and my answer) clarify a significant change in version 13.0.0 and should not be considered as a duplication of an older question with another scope.

Comment: @MichaelE2 In 12.2, [The default element for `Import[file,"PDF"]`  changed from Graphics to Image.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Done. (Just fyi, the answer to the question you linked refers to the link I provided in a comment to the question.)

Comment: @Alan I thought it might be, but I didn't click. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It's all resolved. I hope there's no point in arguing further about our respective interpretations of the original problem statement.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### TL;DR

> Has the default changed for some import option?

From the investigation given below we see **three important changes**:

1. By default FrontEnd of version 13.0.0 [applies to the whole Notebook window a **hidden scale of 96/72**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/260927/280) upon rendering on the Windows OS. This unnecessary scaling is the only reason for the observed low image rendering quality in the FrontEnd.
2. The reason why you didn't notice this when pasting an `image` from the clipboard is that **in version 13.0.0 the FrontEnd by default sets `ImageResolution -> {96., 96.}` for the `image` in the clipboard**. Then upon conversion into boxes, it sets the `ImageSizeRaw` option of obtained `GraphicsBox` to the value equal to `(72/96)*ImageDimensions[image]`. This often results in **non-integer values of `ImageSizeRaw`**, which in turn leads to **rounding them down** by the FrontEnd and in turn also low image rendering quality after applying the hidden scale factor 96/72. But when the `image` is large this effect is not so apparent as when you `Import` the image. You can see these effects yourself:

   ```
   img = RandomImage[1, {110, 113}, ImageResolution -> 96]
   Options[ToBoxes[img], ImageSizeRaw]
   ```

[image: screenshot]

3. Despite the `ImageSize -> 144` explicitly specified in `g1`, export to PDF of version 12.3.1 sets `ImageSize -> 104`, while in version 13.0.0 it correctly sets `ImageSize -> 144`.

Note that it is possible to disable applying the 96/72 scale in version 13.0.0 using the undocumented FrontEnd option [`"ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/260927/mathematica-13-everything-is-magnified#comment649662_260927) (you should restart *Mathematica* after evaluating this):

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode"] = True
```

But this only works if all of your displays are [set to 100% under the "Display" in the Windows "Settings" application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwjpI.png). And of course, there is no guarantee that this will continue to work in future *Mathematica* versions.

Another possible workaround is to apply default `Magnification -> 72/96` [to all `GraphicsBox` objects in the FrontEnd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124531/280) (`Image` appears inside of a Notebook as `GraphicsBox`, as well as `Graphics`):

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, GraphicsBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 72/96}]
```

After evaluating this the described problem disappears:

[image: screenshot]

---

### The investigation

[Starting from version 12.2, the default import element for PDF format is `"PageImages"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html#1396806680), which means that the contents of the pages will be rasterized upon import. Let us compare `ImageDimensions` of obtained images (on Windows 10 x64):

```
Export["temp.pdf", g1];
im = First@Import["temp.pdf"]
im // ImageDimensions
```

With version 12.3.1 (Notebook Magnification is set to 100%):

[image: screenshot]

With version 13.0.0 (Notebook Magnification is set to 100%):

[image: screesnhot2]

We see that the dimensions of the obtained images are substantially different. Even more interesting, here is what happens when we import in version 12 the PDF exported from version 13, and vice versa:

[image: screesnhot3]

[image: screesnhot4]

Let us import them as `"PageGraphics"` instead and check the values of the `ImageSize` option:

```
gr12 = First@Import["ver12.3.1.pdf", "PageGraphics"]
gr13 = First@Import["ver13.0.0.pdf", "PageGraphics"]
Options[#, ImageSize] & /@ {gr12, gr13}
```

[image: screenshot]

Indeed, `ImageSize`s are different and equal to `ImageDimensions` obtained with version 12.3.1.

So, from where come `ImageDimensions` obtained with version 13?

[By default under Windows *Mathematica* 13 uses hidden global magnification](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/260927/280) equal to 96/72:

```
SystemInformation["Devices", "ConnectedDisplays"]
```

[image: screenshot7]

Multiplying 104 and 144 by 1.33333333 and rounding produces 139 and 192, correspondingly.

The actual reason for the low quality of displayed images in version 13 is that they are magnified by the factor of 96/72 by default. Let us try to overcome this by magnifying them by the factor of 72/96 **in version 13.0.0**:

```
Image[Import@"ver12.3.1.pdf", Magnification -> 72/96]
Image[Import@"ver13.0.0.pdf", Magnification -> 72/96]
```

[image: screesnhot8]

We see that the quality is actually quite good.

Comment: fyi, before I tried this option `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode"] = True` which is supposed to make V 13 work as before these changes to dpi were made but this had no effect (need to started frontend for this option to take effect).

Comment: @Nasser It works for me. Note that [this only works if all of your displays are set to 100% under the display settings in the Settings app](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/260927/mathematica-13-everything-is-magnified#comment649662_260927). What is your Windows Magnification setting (not *Mathematica*, but Windows)?

Comment: @Nasser I mean this setting:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwjpI.png

Comment: Ah, yes, that is why it had no effect for me. My display is not set to be 100%. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser I updated the answer with another workaround which should work in your case: `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, GraphicsBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 72/96}]`.

Comment: This made me irrationally angry.

Comment: What is more crazy is that svg renderer could HAVE BEEN used everywhere: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CornuSpiral.html or https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConformalMapping.html And yes, you can do animation in svg. It is very heavy on GPU renderer in chrome, but still works.