# ImageDimensions[Plot[something]] : where does ratio 1.666... come from

Tags: plotting, image, options

From my knowledge, `ImageSize` is an option that adjust the width of an image.

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Axes -> False, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 100] // ImageDimensions

{167,167}

Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Axes -> False, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 1000] // ImageDimensions

{1667,1667}
```

The numbe 167, 1667 may be related to 5/3 = 1.66666......

I think it would be better if the result was {100,100} and {1000,1000}.

Where does the ratio 1.66666...... come from ?

Comment: Why aren't you using `Rasterize[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### UPDATE

Ian Hojnicki [clarifies](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270589/imagedimensionsplotsomething-where-does-ratio-1-666-come-from/270591?noredirect=1#comment675413_270591) in the comments:

> It’s not really magnification. It’s just how you convert points into pixels. They are different units after all. – ihojnicki

Therefore, what I call "magnification" in the original answer should be called "conversion factor" from points to pixels.

---

### Original answer

[By default under Windows *Mathematica* 13 uses hidden global magnification equal to 96/72](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/260927/280):

```
SystemInformation["Devices", "ConnectedDisplays"]
```

[image: screeenshot]

On my system the display scale is set to 100% [under the "Display" in the Windows "Settings" application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwjpI.png), and your code returns `Ceiling[size*96/72.]`:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   ImageSize -> 1000] // ImageDimensions
```

> ```
> {1334, 1334}
> ```

```
Table[Ceiling[size*96/72.], {size, {100, 1000, 10000}}]
```

> ```
> {134, 1334, 13334}
> ```

Probably your display scale is set to 125%, and hence you get the value `Ceiling[size*1.25*96/72.]`:

```
Table[Ceiling[size*1.25*96/72.], {size, {100, 1000, 10000}}]
```

> ```
> {167, 1667, 16667}
> ```

---

See also this answer of mine for additional information:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/263588/280

Comment: Thank you for fast answer!

Comment: @imidak You are welcome!

Comment: It’s not really magnification. It’s just how you convert points into pixels. They are different units after all.