# For Graphics, ImageDimensions yields slightly different value

Tags: graphics, options, rendering, rasterize

I use Mathematica version 12.2, Windows 10.

```
Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {200, 300}]}, ImageSize -> 200] // ImageDimensions
{200, 296}
```

I think the output shoud be {200, 300}, not {200,296}.
I added `ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}` options, but the result was the same.

```
Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {200, 300}]}, ImageSize -> 200, 
  ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}] // ImageDimensions
{200, 296}
```

Similary,

```
for {200, 300} I get {200, 296}
for {200, 200} I get {200, 200}
for {200, 100}, I get {200, 104}
for {200, 10}, I get {200, 26}
for {200, 1}, I get {200, 26}
```

I don't see any reasonable level of rules that are satisfactory.
And how can I create x times y pixeled rectangle ? (if it is finally exported)

Also I Add a code to accurately represent the state of my Mathematica :

```
SystemInformation["Devices", "ConnectedDisplays"]

{{"Region" -> {{0., 1152.}, {0., 615.6}}, 
  "FullRegion" -> {{0., 1152.}, {0., 648.}}, 
  "PixelDimensions" -> {1920, 1080}, "BitDepth" -> 32, 
  "Resolution" -> 120., "Scale" -> 1.66667}}

SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 GraphicsBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 3/5}];
```

(* I applied this option this time *)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For obtaining the true image size in printer's points, one should wrap the expression with `Annotation` and use `Rasterize[..., "Regions"]` to get its bounding rectangle:

```
Clear[expr, imageSize]
expr[h_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {200, h}]}, ImageSize -> 200, opts];
imageSize[expr_] := 
 Differences[Rasterize[Annotation[expr, "out", "Region"], "Regions"][[1, 2]]][[1]]

imageSize[expr[300]]
```

> ```
> {200., 295.68}
> ```

(It is possible to use [`ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GraphicsInformation) or [`ResourceFunction["CellBoundingRectangle"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CellBoundingRectangle/) for obtaining the same information.)

As you can see, the vertical size is slightly different than expected. I believe this is a bug in `Graphics` rendering. To get the expected size, you need to specify the option `PlotRangePadding -> None` for `Graphics`:

```
imageSize[expr[300, PlotRangePadding -> None]]
```

> ```
> {200., 300.}
> ```

With the other possible choices for the height you also get the expected result:

```
Table[imageSize[expr[h, PlotRangePadding -> None]], {h, {300, 200, 100, 10, 1}}]
```

> ```
> {{200., 300.}, {200., 200.}, {200., 100.}, {200., 10.}, {200., 1.}}
> ```

You can check what image size you obtain on exporting to a vector graphics format:

```
vectorExportImportPDF[expr_] := 
 First@ImportString[ExportString[expr, "PDF", "AllowRasterization" -> False], 
   If[$VersionNumber >= 12.2, {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}, {"PDF", "Pages"}], 
   "TextOutlines" -> False]

vectorExportImportPDF[expr[300, PlotRangePadding -> None]] // Options
```

> ```
> {ImageSize -> {200., 300.}, PlotRange -> {{0., 200.}, {0., 300.}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic}
> ```

The final rendered image size in pixels depends on the resolution of your monitor and local `Magnification` setting of a Notebook where the graphics is rendered. The pixel size should be equal to the image size in printer's poins times `magnification*resolution/72.`, where `resolution` of your monitor can be obtained from `SystemInformation`:

```
resolution = "Resolution" /. First[SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]]
```

or from `CurrentValue["WindowResolution"]`:

```
resolution = CurrentValue["WindowResolution"]
```

However, note that prior to *Mathematica* 13.0, *by default* on Windows the monitor resolution was always assumed to be `72.`. Since you're using version 12.2 on Windows and `SystemInformation` reports a monitor resolution of `120.`, you've probably disabled the compatibility mode via the option [`"ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode"`](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2478887). [Starting from version 13.0 the compatibility mode by default is off](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/260927/280), and `SystemInformation` reports the true resolution of the monitor (taking into account the [scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwjpI.png) set at the OS level).

The local `Magnification` option *by default* is inherited from Notebook's `Magnification`:

```
magnification = CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification]
```

But in your case for `Graphics` (and `Image` without explicit `Magnification` option) it will be equal to `3/5` because you have set a fixed `Magnification` for `GraphicsBox` via global `GraphicsBoxOptions`:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, GraphicsBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 3/5}];
```

---

Related MMa.SE threads:

- [Mathematica 13: everything is magnified](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/260927/280)
- [Why in Mathematica 13 do imported PDFs have lower image quality?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/263578/280)
- [How to display PNG image in notebook with best quality](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/273205/280)

Related WC threads:

- [Changing screen resolution in Mathematica V12.1.1 ?](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2478462)
- [Working with Graphics on Windows in a pixel perfect way](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2468048)

Comment: Thank you very much, I think it is still not easy to create an image with small width or small height. I have an idea, a kind of workaround, but haven't tried it yet : embed the  graphic that I want onto a slightly larger graphic(over 26 pixels), then export to image, then crop the image. Do you think it is a good idea..?

Comment: @imidak It is not difficult. Just use `Rasterize` with the option `RasterSize`. For example, `Rasterize[Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}]], RasterSize -> 15]`.