# How to display an image at native size on a display using CreatePalette?

Tags: image, windows, palettes

I am trying to display an image in a new Notebook, centered on the display, using CreatePalette. Here is example code:

```
CreatePalette[image, WindowSize -> All, 
 WindowMargins -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 WindowTitle -> None, WindowFrame -> "Frameless", 
 WindowFloating -> True]
```

This works, but when the image is small (e.g. 32 x 32) the image is magnified. Using an option such as

```
WindowSize -> ImageDimensions[image]
```

does not work.
How do I get it to display at native size?

Comment: closely related: [What governs images resizing in the FrontEnd environment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/106204/5478)

Comment: `Pane` and `ImageSizeMultipliers` don't work but `ImageSize` works:  `RandomImage[1, {12, 12}, ImageSize -> 12]`.