# size of images in dialogboxes

Tags: image, dialog-window, user-interface

I am having issues with the size of multiple images in dialog boxes.
I am trying to create a dialog box that handles three images (red green and blue channels obtained by a microscope) with color and brightness sliders for each channel and displays dynamically the Adjusted image.

The code I wrote is the following (where myChannel1, myChannel2 and myChannel3 are 16 bit 1456x944 pixel images):

```
mB1 = Slider[Dynamic[myBrightness1], {-5, 5, .01}, Appearance -> "Labeled"];
mB2 = Slider[Dynamic[myBrightness2], {-5, 5, .01}, Appearance -> "Labeled"];
mB3 = Slider[Dynamic[myBrightness3], {-5, 5, .01}, Appearance -> "Labeled"];
mC1 = Slider[Dynamic[myContrast1], {-5, 5, .01}, Appearance -> "Labeled"];
mC2 = Slider[Dynamic[myContrast2], {-5, 5, .01}, Appearance -> "Labeled"];
mC3 = Slider[Dynamic[myContrast3], {-5, 5, .01}, Appearance -> "Labeled"];
mIAC1 = Dynamic[ImageAdjust[myChannel1, {myBrightness1, myContrast1}]];
mIAC2 = Dynamic[ImageAdjust[myChannel2, {myBrightness2, myContrast2}]];
mIAC3 = Dynamic[ImageAdjust[myChannel3, {myBrightness3, myContrast3}]];
CreateDialog[{"Edit Contrast and Brightness",
Column[{
 Row[{
   Column[{"Channel1", "---", "Brightness", mB1, "Contrast", mC1, 
     mIAC1}, Alignment -> Center
    ],
   Column[{"Channel2", "---", "Brightness", mB2, "Contrast", mC2, 
     mIAC2}, Alignment -> Center
    ],
   Column[{"Channel3", "---", "Brightness", mB3, "Contrast", mC3, 
     mIAC3}, Alignment -> Center
    ]
   }]
 }],
DefaultButton[]}, WindowSize -> Large]
```

My problem is that the images in the dialog box are too small despite the abundance of space in the dialogbox

[image: See how small the pictures are compared to the available space]

I could not find a way to resize the images,
Any help is apreciate

Thank you,

Comment: You can wrap them with `Image` and set `ImageSize`, use `Pane` etc. See [8583](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8583/5478) and let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! The post you refer to indeed resolves the issue